# Setting longtitude altitude latitude in postgres

Tags: postgis, postgresql

what datatype should I use for a geometry field that uses longtitude altitutde latitutde ?

I'm using a point but that's not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

In PostGIS, you would want POINTZ to store X, Y, and Z values.

```
CREATE TABLE testgeog(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, the_geog geography(POINTZ,4326) );
```